# How to prevent bind from mutating original object in node.js when using async.series?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bind, node-async

I have the following test code:

```
var async = require('async');

var GROUP = 'testGroup';

var opts = {
  someKey: 'hi',
};

test(opts);

function test(options) {
  async.series([
    doThis.bind(null, options),
    doThat.bind(null, options),
  ], function(results) {
    debugger;
  });
}

function doThis(options, cb) {
  options.someKey = [GROUP, options.someKey].join('.');
  return cb();
}

function doThat(options, cb) {
  debugger;
  options.someKey = [GROUP, options.someKey].join('.');
  return cb();
}
```

When we hit the `debugger` in `doThat()`, `options.someKey` already has the value `someGROUP.hi`, so when the function finishes we end up with `options.someKey === 'someGROUP.someGroup.hi'`

How do we bind such that the original object does not change? The bind is necessary because we need to pass in options to the functions that run within `async.series`. Otherwise, we could just invoke the functions and pass in the object as a parameter.

Comment: If you don't want to change the original object, then make a copy of it before modifying it.  Or pass a copy.  Objects are passed by pointer so any changes you make to it in the function will change the original unless you explicitly make a copy of the object somewhere to avoid changing the original.

Comment: Did not know they were always passed as pointers. Do you know where I can find a link of data-types passed as pointers? As this point I'm assuming only complex vars, like objects, arrays, classes?

Comment: Objects are passed as pointers.  This includes a plain object, an array, a custom object (anything that has `typeof obj === "object"` as these are all objects, except `null` which is a weird exception).  Strings are probably passed by pointer too (for internal language efficiency reasons), but strings are immutable so you can't change the string object so it doesn't really matter to your code.  Primitives like numbers and booleans are passed by value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't think  your partially applying the options parameter to your ***doThis()***, ***doThat()*** functions is especially  pertinent.

You're passing the same javascript object/literal as aparameter to two functions and and then mutate that parameter.

If you don't to mutate that object then don't. Find some other way of returning the results of your operation. ***doThis()*** and ***doThat()*** could return values instead of modifying the parameter. You could gather them up in the final callback after the series gets called.

If you just want to preserve the intital value of opts, use lodash or something to make a deep clone of opts before you pass it into test.